# Complex rewrite rules with multiple variables, some the same

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to add some rewrite rules for a member based directory that is filterable

So for instance if I had the following URLs

```
www.example.com/members/location=gb/

www.example.com/members/location=gb/role=director/
```

I would normally just do this as such

```
$member_page_id = 123;
add_rewrite_rule( 'members/search/location =([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=' . $member_page_id . '&location=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule( 'members/search/location =([^/]+)/role=([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=' . $member_page_id . '&location=$matches[1]&role=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

But how can I rewrite these if I want to have multiple variables of the same or they are selected in a different order, say:

```
www.example.com/members/location=gb/location=us/role=director/

www.example.com/members/location=gb/role=director/location=us/
```

I can probably re-order the search string with parse query so it's always say location first then role so as not to have multiple URLs for the same page but how do I add a rewrite rule when there is an unknown amount of variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I got around it by doing the following

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'members/search/(.+?)?$',
    'index.php?page_id=' . $member_page_id . '&search=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

So essentially getting everything after the search then dealing that when parsing the query
I then parsed the query like so from the 'search' query_var

```
function wpse_set_pre_get_users( $query ){
    if( ! is_admin() ){

        $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_new_query = array();

        if( get_query_var( 'search' ) != '' ){
            $search_arr = explode( '/', get_query_var( 'search' ) );

            foreach ( $search_arr as $search_val ) {
                $vals = explode( '=', $search_val );

                $serialize_value = serialize( strval( urldecode( $vals[ 0 ] ) ) );
                $meta_new_query = array(
                    array(
                        'key' => $vals[ 1 ],
                        'value' => trim( urldecode( $vals[ 0 ] ) ),
                        'compare' => '=',
                    ), 
                    array(
                        'key' => $vals[ 1 ],
                        'value' => trim( urldecode( $vals[ 0 ] ) ),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ), 
                    array(
                        'key' => $vals[ 1 ],
                        'value' => trim( $serialize_value ),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ), 
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                );
                $meta_query = array_merge( $meta_query, array( $meta_new_query ) );
            }

            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_users','wpse_set_pre_get_users' );
```